# Channel entry title updated with member email

Tags: channel-entries

I had developed an extension (hooked with zoo_visitor_register_end) using Channel Entry API which creates a new channel entry by setting the title of this entry with a custom field value of Zoo Visitors.

But faced a sudden strange problem. Now its updating the new channel entry's title with member's email.

Everything was working great since more than 5 months. The problem came after updating EE 2.5.5 (2 weeks ago). Site is MSM.

I am hitting my head since yesterday but couldn't find any pointer. I 'll highly appreciate your help.

Edited ***
Below is the code I am using to create new entry via channel entry API:

```
$this->EE->load->library('api');
$this->EE->api->instantiate('channel_entries');
$this->EE->api->instantiate('channel_fields');

$data = array(
        'title'         => $member_data['CUSTOM_FIELD'],
        'entry_date'    => $this->EE->localize->now,
        'author_id'     => $member_id,
        'status'    => 'new',
        'site_id'   => $this->EE->config->item('site_id'),
        'channel_id'    => 14
);

if ($this->EE->api_channel_entries->submit_new_entry(14, $data) === FALSE)
{
    $errors = $this->EE->api_channel_entries->errors ;
}
else
{
    $entry_id = $this->EE->api_channel_entries->entry_id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to pass the 'entry_id' index in the data array. It seems redundant, but I have ran into the same issue. Report back and let me know if this fixes your issue.

```
$data['entry_id'] = $entry_id;

$this->EE->api_channel_entries->update_entry($entry_id, $data);
```

*It's important note, this is deprecated as of 2.6*

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/api/api_channel_entries.html#update-entry

Comment: Thanks justin, but I 'm using EE v2.5.5 and I am creating new entry not updating existing entry. I updated the question with the code.